# amCharts XY Chart dateAxis displays wrong dates

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying out amCharts the XY Chart. For X I use DateAxis.

```js
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
```

All is great as long for the `"date"` I provide `new Date()`:

```js
"date": new Date(iso_date)
```

But now I want to use different timezone to be used for DateAxis. I managed to convert dates with luxon with `toHTTP()` from this:

```js
"[native Date Wed Jul 15 2020 08:21:00 GMT+0930 (Australian Central Standard Time)]"
```

to something like this:

```js
"Tue, 14 Jul 2020 04:01:13 GMT"
```

And finally my chart data was correct. But now the timeline spans in completely wrong period. It's somewhere in the future in 2021 and it spans for the whole year (I'm using single day data).

How can I fix it? Or is there a way to use ISO dates - on default it rejects it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your data, your issue is very likely due to using `new Date()` on a string. If your date string does not strictly adhere to ISO 8601 or RFC 2822, then you're gambling on whether the browser will convert the date correctly ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#Timestamp_string)) and since AmCharts will use the Date object as provided, it's very likely that the string did not exactly match one of the formats.

That said, if you're using string dates, just use AmCharts' DateFormatter object and set its `inputDateFormat` [to the matching format](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/formatters/formatting-date-time/), i.e. `chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd'`, so that it can parse your string dates correctly (or use a third party parser like Moment.js and pass in the converted dates). Also make sure your date axis' `baseInterval` [is set correctly](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/date-axis/#Manually_specifying_data_granularity).

Comment: Thanks. I will try that out within next few days and let you know if that worked!